# Duplicate Messages Published on Kafka Topic Using Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am very new to Springboot and Kafka. Working on a school assignment where using a Springboot app we need to publish Json data on a Kafka topic. My publishing .java file looks as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.CMPE172.kafka.springbootkafkaproducerexample.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("kafka")
public class UserResource {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;
    private final static String TOPIC = "Kafka";

    @GetMapping("/publish/{name}")
    public String Post(@PathVariable("name") final String name) {

        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, new User(name, "Technology", 12000L));
        return "Published successfully";
   }
}
```

Where User is just a normal Java class with constructor, getters and setters.
My configuration file looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import com.CMPE172.kafka.springbootkafkaproducerexample.model.User;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> produceFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG ,  "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ,  StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ,  JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
   public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(produceFactory());
    }

}
```

After starting the zookeeper and Kafka servers successfully, I'm creating a new topic using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions    
1 --topic Kafka
```

I then start a consumer using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic Kafka --from-  
beginning
```

I can then successfully publish Json messages/objects in the topic by simply going to localhost:8081/kafka/publish/Adam   (Json object with name Adam, dept "Technology" and salary 12000 is being published in this case)

Problem/bug: each time I publish a new name, the name that I published previously is displayed for the second time. For example, if I go to localhost:8081/kafka/publish/Jim Json file containing Adam is published again along with Jim. Furthermore, if I restart all servers, publishing new Json data seems to invoke publishing names that were published previously before the server was restarted.

Long story short, looking at online videos, each publication should published only 1 name at a time and nothing else. In my case, however, I get duplicate values published with each new publication. Could anybody please point me in the right direction? All help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you are publishing more than once, but are you executing that console consumer each time you publish, or leaving the same command running? If the former then that explains it as you are displaying all messages that have been published on that topic.

Comment: I am leaving the same consumer terminal running, not touching it at all. I only publish from browser. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjHYWEV_E_o  Each time the guy publishes to topic here, JSON object is published only once. It is not the case with me, however.

Comment: Publishing more than once is possible but only really if you have acks=all rather than the default acks=1. This is because the send method is actually asynchronous. It returns immediately and a background thread sends batches of messages, retrying if acknowledgement is not received

Comment: Hmm - can't see anything wrong with your code (though I might argue with your use of Get, from a RESTful perspective :-) . So the actual send would be retried if the leader broker didn't successfully store the message but you would see some logging I think. A few experiments then. If you delete your topic contents (just remove the log directories defined in your broker config and run your console consumer from beginning to check nothing there then stop it) then call the API say 3 times, then run console consumer - how many messages are there, 6 or 3?

Comment: Apologies as I'm heading off but will check for updates in the morning - there is always a rational explanation. I note that you only have 1 replica so you have the simplest setup which is good for experimenting.

Comment: I'll try it in a bit. In the meantime, I can tell you that whenever I publish a new name 3 JSON objects are being published on the Kafka topic: object with name Alexander (published earlier), object with just inserted name and object whose name alphabetically precedes the just inserted object. Weird.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly fine if I publish through Chrome rather than Safari (as I was doing before), so I guess this may be Safari issue. Thank you very much for your help, Chris!

Comment: Cool, glad it got sorted. I was going to narrow it down to all possible causes - 1. Somehow calling API more than once, 2. code calling publisher.send more than one 3. retries in publishing thread due to failure to receive acknowledgement from leader 4. consumer rebalance (unlikely but if you had more than one console consumer running in the same group) 5. user error in using console consumer. Sounds like it was 1. Very odd though!

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to a log. Each request creates a brand new message, not overwrites old ones.

The fact that you have `--from-beginning` means that you'll always scan every message of the topic from the beginning rather than waiting for new messages to arrive.

If you truly think there's duplicate messages being posted, you may use OffsetShell to list the latest offsets of the topic

Comment: It works perfectly fine from Chrome browser. The above issue only occurs when I publish from Safari, for some reason.